# Need to generate an absent report based on days worked table data

Tags: mysql

This is my first question. So please bear with me if I have asked something stupid.

I have two tables in my mySql database named 'users', 'user_checkin_checkout'

Each time a user logs in to the website, I create a new record in 'user_checkin_checkout' table, and when user logs out, I update that record with current time.

Table structure:

```
# Users

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)

# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_checkin_checkout` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `checkin_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkout_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkin_ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `checkout_ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

Now, I need to generate a report so that it takes from and to date as parameters, and I want to know when the users were **absent** (not checked in). I am struggling to generate a query for this. I am unable to use join queries between them as that just brings when the user has actually checked in. Should I just have another table that populates all days between entered days and should I use a join with that table instead? Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get record when user was checked in, not the record , when user was not checked in, but you can do it by total - checkin

Comment: yes, i can get record on when user has checked in.. But what i need is report of when user has NOT checked in

Comment: let's you have an array of checkedin, and you can make an array from , fromdate to todate, then you can get array_diff for not checked in

Comment: 'generate a report' - ??

Comment: @developerCK - say I have 300 employees in users table. If I go with your solution, I should iterate all records (say in a year span it will reach 75000 records), and i think that is tedious.

Comment: You can make a stored procedure for same , i think it will be much better rather than maintaining a extra table, or you can make a middle table userid->perdate->attendance, nf3 form of db, that can simpler your task